# How to reload an image once it failed to load using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

When loading large amount of images at once, every once in a while a few of them fail to load. If i visit the link of the failed image on a new tab, it loads up back where it failed to load, maybe from cache but i am not sure. I found the code below which detects if an image has loaded or failed, i tried to make it so it reloads the image once its failed but it does not work. Would there be any way to make the code work so it keeps reloading the image until it loads once it fails to load?

```js
var $posts = $(this.responseText); //ajax response
$posts.find(".icon").each(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("data-src")
  var reload = $(this).attr("data-src")
  testImage(url)

  function testImage(url) {
    var tester = new Image();
    tester.onerror = imageNotFound;
    tester.src = url;
  }

  function imageNotFound() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = reload
    console.log("reloaded")
    $(this).Lazy({
      effect: 'fadeIn',
      effectTime: 500,
      visibleOnly: true
    });
  }
```

In the code i use `data-src` instead of `src` because i am using the lazyloading plugin, i re-initialize the plugin on the link once the function is called, if i disable the lazy loading plugin and only use the src of the image it makes no difference.

Comment: Add a timestamp to the reload location to prevent it being read from cache: `img.src = reload + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();`. That being said, it sounds like you're loading that many images you're flooding the server with requests and some are timing out. If that's the case reduce the number of images you show using lazy loading, or use a distributed CDN for hosting them

Comment: No. It has quotes around it.

Comment: i am using google api to load images, i load around 20 images on each ajax call and my api key is set to load way more than that in 100 seconds so flooding the server should not be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, Google should be able to handle that :)

Comment: What's the error message you're getting for the failed images in the browser network tab?

Comment: i get a status code 403 without any message. The response shows as "No Response Data Available". Anyhow, jquery does detect that the image failed to load using the code above and visiting the link directly makes it load back up so my requirement is to reload it once its failed.